# Reasonably performant hex decoding in native bash?

Tags: bash

I have a 2MB file which is a sequence of hex values delimited by spaces. For example:

```
3F 41 56 00 00
```

Easy peasy to do this in Bash:

```
cat hex.txt | tr -s " " $'\n' | while read a; do 
    echo $a | xxd -r -p | tee -a ascii
done
```

or

```
f=$(cat hex.txt)
for a in $f; do
    echo $a | xxd -r -p | tee -a ascii
done
```

Both are excruciatingly slow.

I whipped up a C program which converted the file in about about two seconds and later realized that I could have just done this:

```
cat hex.txt | xxd -r -p
```

As I've already converted the file and found an optimal solution, my question isn't about the conversion process itself but rather how to optimize my first two attempts as if the third were not possible. Is there anything to be done to speed up these one-liners or is Bash just too slow for this?

Comment: bash loops are just not very fast I think.

Comment: Your `bash` script isn't a single program; you're running a new program for *every* line of the input. *That's* the bottleneck, and you fixed it with a single call to `xxd`. Nothing else is going to make the first two attempts significantly faster.

Comment: Incidentally, there do exist capable shells for which doing native loops isn't so inherently slow -- if you have a proper David Korn build of ksh93 (performance of the third-party clones varies), performance numbers close to those of awk aren't unheard of. Bash, however, is not at all built for speed.

Comment: Any time you want to type `cat | ....`  **STOP**, you are engaged in a **UUoC** (Unnecessary Use of Cat). Redirection saves spawning a separate subshell. (e.g. `xxd -r -p <hex.txt`). Make it a point, avoid all **UUoC**!

Comment: Where performance is a non-issue (small files and anything outside of a loop) I tend or prefer using `cat |` to keep code as readable from left-to-right as much as possible. Using `cat` in this case only causes a minor delay before the expression begins evaluating the loop; as it's used outside of the loop, it has no bearing on performance in this case.

Comment: @Zhro I used to feel the same way, but I now I tend to use  `<hex.txt xxd -r -p`. That gives you both the small performance benefit and the left-to-righ flow, and it shuts up people who come screaming UUoC.

Comment: Regarding UUOC, `xxd` supports an input file. So just use `xxd -r -p hex.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

It's slow because you're invoking two programs,
`xxd` and `tee`,
in each iteration of the loop.

Using the `printf` builtin should be more loop-friendly, and you only need one instance of `tee`:

```
tr -s " " '\n' < hex.txt | 
while read seq; do printf "\x$seq"; done |
tee -a ascii
```

(You might not be needing the `-a` switch to `tee` anymore).

(
If you want to use a use a scripting language, `ruby` is another good choice beside `awk`:

```
tr -s " " '\n' < hex.txt |  ruby -pe '$_ = $_.to_i(16).chr'
```

(Much faster than the in-bash version).
)

Comment: Nice job of optimizing the bash loop to not call _external_ utilities in every iteration, but the intrinsic slowness of `bash` loops cannot be overcome.
Delightfully short, yet readable Ruby solution that also performs reasonably well.
Note that while `ruby -040 -pe '$_ = $_.to_i(16).chr' hex.txt` could do it as _one_ command, your  `tr` / pipeline combo is actually faster, at least on my OSX 10.10 system.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following - unfortunately, the solution varies by `awk` implementation used:

```
# BSD/OSX awk
xargs printf '0x%s ' < hex.txt | awk -v RS=' ' '{ printf "%c", $0 }' > ascii

# GNU awk; option -n needed to support hex. numbers
xargs printf '0x%s ' < hex.txt | awk -n -v RS=' ' '{ printf "%c", $0 }' > ascii

# mawk - sadly, printf "%c" only works with letters and numbers if the input is *hex*
awk  -v RS=' ' '{ printf "%c", int(sprintf("%d", "0x" $0)) }' < hex.txt
```

With a 2MB input file, the timings on my late-2012 iMac with 3.2 GHz Intel Core i5 and a Fusion Drive, running OSX 10.10.3 are as follows:

- *BSD/OSX* awk: ca. `1s`
- *GNU* awk: ca. `0.6s`
- *mawk*: ca. `0.5s`

Contrast this with [PSkocik's optimized-bash-loop solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30201031/45375): ca. `11s`

<sup>It's tempting to think that the `mawk` solution, given that it's a *single command without a pipeline*, should be the faster solution with *all* `awk` implementations, but in practice it is *not*. Here's a version that works with all three implementations with `-n` for *GNU* awk provided on demand: `awk $([[ $(gawk --version 2>/dev/null) = GNU* ]] && printf %s -n) -v RS=' ' '{ printf "%c", int(sprintf("%d", "0x" $0)) }' < hex.txt`</sup>

The **speed increase comes from avoiding `bash` loops altogether** and letting *utilities* do the work:

- `xargs printf '0x%s ' < hex.txt` prefixes all values in `hex.txt` with `0x` so that `awk` will later recognize them as hexadecimals.

  - Note that, depending on your platform, the command line that `xargs` constructs with all stdin input tokens as arguments may exceed the maximum command-line length as reported by `getconf ARG_MAX` - fortunately, `xargs` is smart enough to then invoke the command *multiple* times, fitting as many arguments as possible on the command line each time.
- `awk -v RS=' ' '{ printf "%c", $0 }'`

  - `awk -v RS=' '` reads each space-separated token - i.e., each hex. value - as a separate input record
  - `printf "%c", $0` then simply converts each record into its ASCII-character equivalent using `printf`.

---

**Generally speaking:**

- **Bash loops** with large iteration counts are ***intrinsically* slow**.
- It gets **much worse** if you also **call an *external* utility in *every iteration***.
  <sup>See Charles Duffy's comments below.</sup>

For good performance with large iteration counts, **avoid bash loops and let external utilities do the iteration work**.

Comment: I agree with both points, but the second (external utility invocation) is orders of magnitude worse than the first (inherently slow performance).

Comment: ...and when I say "orders of magnitude", I mean "hundreds of thousands of iterations per second" vs "just over a thousand iterations per second" -- so two orders of magnitude base 10, or eight orders of magnitude base 2 -- in my own very unscientific local benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesDuffy. I've updated the wording, but to clarify: what  are you comparing in your iteration-count statement? A pure bash loop with a bash loop that invokes a utility?

Comment: Assumption spot-on; in one case, a loop that does nothing but increment a counter; another that invokes an external utility that immediately exits, and _then_ increments the counter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thanks for that; I've updated my answer to point to your comments.

Comment: It only outputs zeros for `3F 41 56 00 00`, though. The output should be equal to `echo 3F 41 56 00 00|tr ' ' '\n'| xxd -r -p`. (Something like `?AV`)

Comment: @PSkocik: Thanks for the feedback; sounds like you hit on a bug in `mawk`, unless I'm missing something: when you pass a *hex*. number string to `printf "%c"`, `mawk` inexplicably prints `0` for anything other than a letter or number; this problem does not surface with *decimal* numbers; try `mawk '{ printf "%c\n%c\n", $1, $2  }' <<<$'0x41 65\n0x3f 63'`. I've included a single-command workaround above, which actually happens to be the fastest solution overall, but, interestingly, it is the original _pipeline_-based solution that's relatively faster for GNU and BSD awk.

Comment: Works great now. Both the newly added mawk and gawk version. It translates a 16 MB sample in about 2.5 s, which takes my bash loop about a minute (220ms for xxd).

Comment: @PSkocik: Cool; I appreciate the follow-up.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can drop the first `cat` and replace it by `tr < hex.txt`.  Then you can also build a static conversion table and drop `echo` and `xxd`.  But the loop will still be slow, and you can't get rid of that, I think.

Comment: It'll be at least a few orders of magnitude faster than it is right now. Not as fast as the C version, of course, but... well, the question is what's fast enough. :)